# Anyway to get all available Tags in a received msg

Tags: list, tags, quickfix

It's straightforward to check whether tag is available by handling FieldNotFound exception. Is there simple anyway I can get a list of tags in an inbound msg by using QuickFix lib?

Comment: seems FieldMap's    <br/> iterator begin() { return m_fields.begin(); }
  iterator end() { return m_fields.end(); } could be the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `isSetField` to check if a tag is available instead of handling the exceptions. As stated by @user2622305, to get a list of the message tags, you can iterate through the message fields using `begin()` and `end()`.

Comment: This will not get tags within repeating groups, though.

Comment: I think begin and end should be the way for me to get all sure tags.